# Relate one table to another table multiple times in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables, say `Table1` and `Secondtable`. `Table1` is having more than one columns that has foreign key to `Secondtable`. Example structure is as below.

```
Table1
ID Name Col1 Col2 Col3

Secondtable
COlID Col1
```

In `Table1`; `Col1, Col2, Col3` are having FK to `Secondtable.ColID`. Now add EF to your application. (In my case its ASP.Net C#). When you see at entity model of `Table1`, It will have three properties of `Secondtable` like below

```
    public virtual Secondtable Secondtable { get; set; }
    public virtual Secondtable Secondtable1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Secondtable Secondtable2 { get; set; }
```

Now add one more column say `BCol` in `Table1` with relation to `Secondtable.ColID`. Update EF in application. Your model will look like

```
    public virtual Secondtable Secondtable { get; set; }
    public virtual Secondtable Secondtable1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Secondtable Secondtable2 { get; set; }
    public virtual Secondtable Secondtable3 { get; set; }
```

The question is how to identify which column relates to `columns of Table1`? I think sql server gives key names in alphabetical order. I.e. in order `Col1, Col2 then Col3`. If you add more columns, it will change the names accordingly ( Bcol, Col1, Col2, Col3). I have to change relation names from model browser in studio when we update edmx.

Is there any simple way to identify the relation? Thanks.
(Comment if the explanation needs to be improved.)

Comment: Which approach are you using: Code First or Database First ?

Comment: Database First.

Comment: *If you add more columns, it will change the names accordingly* No. Sql Server won't change existing constraint names if you add more foreign keys. But why so many associations? Do these four references have distinct different roles? If so, name the foreign keys and the constraints accordingly, so you recognize them in the edmx. If not, convert it into a one-to-many association.